# Why do we need to specify the need for satisfying the closure property when we know that it will always be satisfied?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Wikipedia definition of a Group:

> In mathematics, a group is a set equipped with a binary operation that
>   combines any two elements to form a third element in such a way that
>   four conditions called group axioms are satisfied, namely closure,
>   associativity, identity, and invertibility.

If a set is equipped with a binary operation doesn't it automatically satisfy the closure property? A binary operation on a set $S$ is a mapping of the elements of the Cartesian product $S \times S$ to $S$, so any binary operation on two elements will give an element belonging to the same set.

Now we can have a set equipped with a binary operation where it is not associative example $(\Bbb R,-)$, so it makes sense to specify that it needs to satisfy associativity in order to be called a group.

My question is why do we need to specify the need for satisfying the closure property when we know that it will always be satisfied?

Comment: Yes, but sometimes you need to check that a supposed operation really is an operation (i.e., is closed).

Comment: consider a subgroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a set is equipped with a binary operation doesn't it automatically satisfy the closure property?

Yes.

A binary operation on a set $S$ is indeed a function from $S\times S$ to $S$.

However, pedagogically, it is helpful to leave in closure as an axiom. It's often the first thing to check for a candidate group whether or not one actually has a binary operation.

It's worth mentioning that there are other, equivalent ways of defining a group, [some of which rely on a single axiom](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/projects/gtsax/).